# regex expression not working for validating credit card expiry information

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex expression which matches the expiry date on credit card 
Format I am looking for is mm/yy. Following is my function in javascript

```
validateCreditCardExpiry: function(expiry){
        if(this.isEmpty(expiry))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{2})$/;
        if(!regex.test(expiry))
        {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

I have tried using the above on string such as 12/33 which returns false. Can some one help me out. Thanks

Comment: Your pattern works: https://regex101.com/r/rK7aO8/1 The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: It seems OK for me. May be you have a non printable character in the string.

Comment: it seems that its going in the if(!regex.test(expiry)) and thereby returning false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above regex expression is working correctly. I somehow was introducing spaces between '/'. that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment ([see your working regex here](https://regex101.com/r/rK7aO8/1)), you can very well shorten your function:

```
validateCreditCardExpiry: function(expiry){
    if (expiry) {
        var regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{2})$/;
        if(regex.test(expiry)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or - as [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) pointed out in the comments, even shorter:

```
validateCreditCardExpiry: function(expiry){
    return /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?[0-9]{2}$/.test(expiry);
}
```

Comment: Or just `validateCreditCardExpiry: function(expiry){ return /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?[0-9]{2}$/.test(expiry); }`